# How to not deliver RESTlet service response in chunks

Tags: rest, restlet, chunked

I am using a RESTlet REST web service to deliver data via a GET to my iOS and Android apps.  Occasionally I get errors with the connection on the app side.  I put the url to the service in a browser to invoke a GET and see a response. I noticed that the contents of the service isn't delivered immediately but in chunks or a few lines at a time.  The data type of the response is JSON.

Is there a way to get the entire response in one chunk when the service is invoked?

Comment: How do you produce the JSON content with Restlet?

Comment: In my class that extends Server resource I return a JsonRepresentation object that contains my content.  The only thing I do after that is set the character set for the JsonRepresentation like so: .setCharacterSet(CharacterSet.UTF_8);  Is this correct?

Comment: Is this breaking only for Android or also for iOS?

Comment: This is breaking on both iOS and Android.  Is there a solution?  PS - I love the new book!

Comment: Thanks for the book feed-back! To prevent chunk encoding, you can call the ServerResource#setResponseEntityBuffering(true) method, but this isn't ideal. What kind of HTTP server are you using?

Comment: I am using a tomcat servlet container.  Is above method still the one to use with tomcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call the ServerResource#setResponseEntityBuffering(true) method